# Google Analytics Dashboard - Filter out specific data ON specific date

Tags: date, filter, analytics, dashboard

Scratching my head on this one, I have a set of 6 projects sending data to one dashboard. On September 1 only ONE of those projects sent out a bunch of errors, spiking the data on that date. My goal is to filter out just that one project on just september 1 but I'm not seeing how to combine those two filters, it's either filtering out that one project for all dates or filtering out that date for all projects. Anyone got any ideas on how to remove specific data on only 1 date?

Comment: Had the same issue today, below is how I solved it in dashboards

Answer (score 0):

Go under:

Widget Settings > Filter this data > Don't show > Date > Containing > YYYYMMDD

Screenshot:

[image]